# How to get the access token in python from a URL where oauth2 flow is Resource owner password credential grant

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I need to request a token to fetch the data from an API.
I have below information with me.

```
Oath 2 flow: "Resource owner password credential grant"
Resource Owner Name: "username"
Resource Owner Password: "password"
Client Identification: "clientID"
Client Password: "clientPassword"
Access token URL: "URL"
```

I have been trying multiple ways but all of them seems to fail.
Can anybody suggest what I am missing.

Below is one of the code I am trying, but it fails.

```
import json
import requests

data = { "username" : "somename", "password":"somepassword"}
                                                                                                                                       
headers = {"Client_id": "SomeID", "Client_secret": "SomePassword", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
                                                                                                  
response = requests.get("https://URL/as/token.oauth2", data=data, headers=headers)
if response.status_code in [200]:
    tok_dict = json.loads(response.text)
    print(tok_dict)
    issued_at = tok_dict["issued_at"]
    expires_in = tok_dict["expires_in"]
    token_type = tok_dict["token_type"]
    access_token = tok_dict["access_token"]
else:
    print("error")
    print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Try `json=data` instead of `data=data` in the `get` call

Comment: @C.Nivs Still getting the error.

Comment: Can you format the entire error into the question?

Comment: Are you sure your headers are formatted properly? `Client_id` seems like it would produce a 400 Bad Request. I would expect it to be something like `Client-Id` or `ClientId`

Comment: @C.Nivs Yes that make sense, but I tried changing it both way but same error code, which is 403. but when I am using SOAPUI with same credential It is returning the token but not through Python, I have a feeling it is something to do with the code. Furthermore I am not able to find any proper document to get access token when grant type is Resource owner password credential

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution, adding the code snippet below to help other.

```
import requests
import json
CI = "my client ID"
CS = "my client secret"
UN = "User name"
PW = "password"
url = "token URL"

payload = f"grant_type=password&client_id={CI}&client_secret={CS}&username={UN}&password={PW}"
headers = {'accept': "application/json" , "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

def generate_token():
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    return response.json()["access_token"]
```